# 403 forbidden error in Passenger+Nginx+rails configuration

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have installed nginx+passenger in amazon-linux. By `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`

After I edited `/var/opt/nginx/nginx.conf` as below:

`root  /home/ec2-user/current/public/index;`

```
server {

    listen       80;

    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root  /home/ec2-user/current/public/index;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

I had thrown with 403 forbidden error and so, I checked my path, it was correct.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your permissions are too strict and don't allow Nginx to access your root directory. Relax permissions like this:

```
chmod o+x /home/ec2-user/current
chmod o+x /home/ec2-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your nginx config to point the root just to the `public` folder:

```
root /home/ec2-user/current/public;

server {

    listen       80;

    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root  /home/ec2-user/current/public;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: @Cdub- browser can't establish a connection to the server